# ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory exception although org.slf4j is on the class path

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, logback, slf4j

I am trying to manually build Maven project from the console. mvn clean package builds the project successfully, but once I try to java -jar target/App-1.0.jar I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at services.Executor.<clinit>(Executor.java:23)
        at uk.landbay.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

The dependency tree includes the org.slf4j.LoggerFactory and looks like this:

[Dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ZUP.png)

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>uk.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!--   For work with CSV files   -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--   Logging dependencies   -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--   Testing dependencies   -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>uk.app.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note that the project runs normally and brings no exception when run using the IntelliJ IDE. What could be the problem? I am using Java 11.

Comment: Is the built Jar file a shadow/fat jar (does it only contain your classes or all classes of all used libraries)? If not does it include the necessary class path elements and are the JAR on the configured classpath accessible on the path mentioned in the manifest?

Comment: Creating a fat jar solved the issue. Thank you so much! :) I followed the tutorial here https://javahelps.com/how-to-create-a-fat-jar-using-maven.